# add submenu page doesn't display

Tags: admin-menu, add-submenu-page

I can't display the submenu of my menu when creating a plugin (Beginner).
Could you please help me to find my error?
My plugin is well activated and the menu_page appears well

```
add_action('admin_menu','tictac_admin_menu_option');

function tictac_admin_menu_option()
{
  add_menu_page(
  'Gestion des Horaires',
  'Time Control',
  'manage_options',
  'tictac_admin_menu',
  'tictac_scripts_page',
  //plugins_url( 'time-control/admin/logo/tictac-logo.png' ),
  'dashicons-calendar-alt'
  //16
  );
  add_submenu_page('tictac_admin_menu',
  'Sous menu Opening',
  'Options Opening',
  'tictac_admin_submenu',
  'tictac_scripts_menu',
  'tictac_opening_submenu'
  );

}
function tictac_opening_submenu()
{
  ?>
  <div id="wrap">
    <h1>Add Opening</h1>
  </div>
  <?php
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The fourth parameter in add_submenu_page function is a capability. Try changing it to manage_options so your code looks like this:

```
add_submenu_page('tictac_admin_menu',
  'Sous menu Opening',
  'Options Opening',
  'manage_options',
  'tictac_scripts_menu',
  'tictac_opening_submenu'
```

);

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks it works. But i don't understand why i must choose "Manage_options". The codex does not explain very well

Comment: You don't have to choose "manage_options" capability. I assumed you want this one, because you added it in the add_menu_page function. You have to pass any capability you want as the fourth parameter. You can find the list of available capabilities here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities

"manage_options" is an administrator capability, so it means that only administrators will be able to access these pages